# is it possible to create inner(nested) forms in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

is it possible to create inner( nested ) forms in php

in our application i want to upload user details to mysql server including user recent work ( that is image ). image is stored in my uploads folder and the path of that image is stored in my database. 
that's way i am using inner form to upload image to uploads folder and returns uploaded image path. when the mail form submitted then user details and image path will stored in mysql database this is my idea is it possible or not please give me suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create nested forms in *HTML*, the server side language is irrelevant.

You can have multiple submit buttons and use the value of the successful one (i.e. the one that was used to submit the form) to decide if you should accept an image upload and return to the form (repopulated it with the submitted data) or process the other submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

FORMS are part of HTML and not part of PHP at all. And HTML doesn't allow you to have nested FORMS. The best bet, if you want to upload the image and preview before you submit the actual user data would be to use some JS and an IFRAME to simulate nested forms.

An example of what I explained is here : http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax/ajax_file_upload/

**NOTE** This is NOT an Ajax file upload (noted in the article too). But this will help you do what you are looking for

Comment: thank you for your reply...   <iframe name="uploadiframe" style="display:none" src="uploadimg.php"></iframe>
   <input type="hidden" id="up" value="1" name="up" /> <input type="file" name="file" onchange="document.fileupload.submit();" />
   <div id="attachmentdiv" style="margin-left:30px"></div> i am using the above code to upload image iploadimg.php file uploads the image into my uploads folder and return back to set the hidden field(that is 'up') value to the path of the image but i am unable to find that path after submit the main form..

Comment: It's really hard to read code in comments. Please edit your question and put it there. As for your path issue, I suggest that you use some sort of ID when submitting the image and then when the form is submitted, to use that ID as a reference to find the image